# How do I have dynamic elements in a XAML WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

I have an MVVM WPF application where I display cards for a card game. I am just displaying them on the screen, 4 cards to a row for however many cards are in an observable collection. However, the cards are all different types that all inherit from one base class. Each card type has it's own substantially different view as a user control. So, from my experience, I understand that I can bind the ItemSource property to my observable collection, but how can I specify to use certain user controls based off of the type of the item from my ItemSource? I theorized that I could just load all the user controls for each card and have the visibility of each control turned on or off in a converter based on the card type, but that sounds EXTREMELY inefficient to me. Anyone have any idea?

Comment: You declare a [DataTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms742521(v=vs.100).aspx) for each card type. Alternatively if the cards are all the same class type but specify their type in a property then you use [DataTriggers](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/styles/trigger-datatrigger-event-trigger/) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [DataTemplates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms742521(v=vs.100).aspx).  For example, imagine you have the following classes:

```cs
public class MyViewModel
{
  public List<PersonInfo> DataItems { get; }
    = new List<PersonInfo>()
      {
        new AgeInfo() { Age = 25 },
        new NameInfo() { Name = 13 }
      };
}

public abstract class PersonInfo
{
}

public class AgeInfo : PersonInfo
{
  public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class NameInfo : PersonInfo
{
  public int Name { get; set; }
}
```

You can have an ItemsControl (or ListBox, ListView, etc.) that showed each item according to the data type of the item:

```xml
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataItems}">
  <ItemsControl.Resources>

    <!-- Names are edited via textboxes -->
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:NameInfo}">
      <StackPanel>
        <Label>Name:</Label>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" />
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <!-- Ages are edited via slider -->
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:AgeInfo}">
      <StackPanel>
        <Label>Age:</Label>
        <Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="150" Value="{Binding Age}" />
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

  </ItemsControl.Resources>
</ItemsControl>
```

Where you place the DataTemplate is up to you, but as long as it's in the resource-hierarchy for the control, it will be used.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `ResourceDictionary` for mapping the UI (e.i map View Model to Model) and register it

XAML

```
<ResourceDictionary .....
                    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:...."
                    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:...."
                    >

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:viewModels1}">
        <views:view1 />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:viewModels2}">
        <views:view2 />
    </DataTemplate>

    ...

</ResourceDictionary>
```

C#

```
public static class ViewsMapping
{
    private static bool _isUIMappingRegistered = false;

    public static void Register()
    {
        if (!_isUIMappingRegistered)
        {
            ResourceDictionary MyResourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
            MyResourceDictionary.Source = new Uri(".....", UriKind.Relative);
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(MyResourceDictionary);
            _isUIMappingRegistered = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Then change the **observable collection** to be `ObservableCollection<BaseClass>` and the selected view will present the derived class view.

Comment: This seems way overboard for what the SO is asking. They don't need to be in their own ResourceDictionary, and even if they did you don't need to merge it in code, you can just add it to the app xaml.

Comment: Hi Mark, of course that you are right, the solution just need to be 'match ViewModel to a View' but I still think that the most elegant, ordered and maintainable solution is what I answered.

Comment: Thanks for the input on this answer! Though I do like the simplicity of this solution, it is not in my power for this project to create / deal with resource dictionaries. It's a bit weird but each member of the team has certain roles with certain things they can do, and creating a global resource dictionary is out of my reach for this project.